# Creating multiple sliders and making them function separately from one another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm currently in the middle of building multiple sliders for a website that I'm currently creating. Right now I believe I'm half way into finishing it and have stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to solve

Since there multiple sliders, I've managed to get the `length` or count the number of items display inside the element(`.slider`). The value in the jquery `length` will serve as part of the condition for the `on-click` trigger/event which is the `if` condition below. How can pass the value from the `length` on to the on-click trigger in order to make the slider move left and right

Apologies for my bad English..

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {


 var sliderWrapper      = $('.slider-wrapper'),
     sliderWrapperWidth = sliderWrapper.width(),
     slider             = $('.slider'),
     slideItems         = $('.slider .slide-items'),
     position           = 0;

    //var itemLengths = [];

 $('.slider-wrapper .slider').each(function() {
  var items = $(this).find('.slide-items').length;
  var sliderBox = $(this);

  //itemLengths.push(items.length); 
  slideItems.outerWidth( sliderWrapperWidth / 2 );


  sliderBox.width( slideItems.outerWidth() * items  )
    });

    $('.slider-wrapper .slider .buttons .prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if( position > 0 ) {
            position--;
            $('.slider-wrapper .slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width() });
        }
    });

    $('.slider-wrapper .slider .buttons .next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();

     if( position < totalSlides - 1 ) {
         position++;
         $('.slider-wrapper .slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width() });
     }
    })


})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e5d0d0; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div p {
  color: purple; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px 0; 
}


.container .slider-wrapper .buttons div {
  background-color: cyan; 
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Multiple Sliders</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look in to using `$(this)` inside your events. It selects the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to use `$(this)` in order to move the slides separately.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
$('.slider-wrapper').each(function() {
    var sliderWrapper      = $(this),
        sliderWrapperWidth = sliderWrapper.width(),
        slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
        slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slider .slide-items'),
        position           = 0;

    //itemLengths.push(slideItems.length); 
    slideItems.outerWidth( sliderWrapperWidth / 2 );


    slider.width( slideItems.outerWidth() * slideItems.length  );

    sliderWrapper.find('.buttons .prev').on('click', function(e) {
        ...
    });

    sliderWrapper.find('.buttons .next').on('click', function(e) {
        ...
    });
});
```

that way each instance of the slider will have its own variables and events.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `$(this)` within each click event to store the variables relevant to the current clicked element. I have also added a `data-slide` attribute to each slider which replaces the `position` variable, so that each slider has it's own slider position defined.

I have cleaned up the code a little bit as well because I was bored.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      // store variable relevent to clicked slider
      var sliderWrapper      = $(this).closest('.slider-wrapper'),
         slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
          slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
          currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

      // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
      if( currentSlide > 0 ) {
          // Decremement current slide
          currentSlide--;
          // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
          slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
          // Update data-slide attribute
          sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
      }
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      // store variable relevent to clicked slider
      var sliderWrapper      = $(this).closest('.slider-wrapper'),
         slideItems         = sliderWrapper.find('.slide-items'),
          slider             = sliderWrapper.find('.slider'),
          totalSlides        = slideItems.length,
          currentSlide       = sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide');

    // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
    if( currentSlide < totalSlides - 1 ) {
        // Increment current slide
        currentSlide++;
        // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
        slider.css({'right' : currentSlide*slideItems.outerWidth() });
        // Update data-slide attribute
        sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
    }
  })

});

$(window).on('load', function() {

  $('.slider-wrapper').each(function() {
    var slideItems = $(this).find('.slide-items'),
    items = slideItems.length,
    sliderBox = $(this).find('.slider'),
    sliderWrapperWidth = $(this).width();

    slideItems.outerWidth( sliderWrapperWidth / 2 );
    sliderBox.width( slideItems.outerWidth() * items  );
  });

});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
 v2.0 | 20110126
 License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block; }

body {
line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none; }

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0; }

* {
box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .slider-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e5d0d0;
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div p {
  color: purple;
}

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


.container .slider-wrapper .buttons div {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget ex mi. Etiam a vestibulum ligula, id porta dui. Duis in iaculis quam. Integer aliquam justo nec nibh consequat vulputate.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget ex mi. Etiam a vestibulum ligula, id porta dui. Duis in iaculis quam. Integer aliquam justo nec nibh consequat vulputate.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-wrapper" data-slide="0">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-items">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="prev">prev</div>
        <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your use of selectors. In a nutshell the selectors inside the event function hit both sliders. But the answer is not as simple as just using $(this). Here's the longer answer:

A lot of the power of jquery is that it makes adding listeners to element events trivial. Lets take apart a piece of your code to understand what is going on:

```
$('.slider-wrapper .slider .buttons .prev').on('click', function(e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if( position > 0 ) {
        position--;
        $('.slider-wrapper .slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width() });
    }
});
```

The line `$('.slider-wrapper .slider .buttons .prev')` is an element *selector*, and it says `find ALL elements that have hierarchy of classes 'slider-wrapper slider buttons prev'`. Note the ALL - this is where your code goes wrong - we will fix it in a moment. The end of that line is `.on('click', function(e) {` which is saying `for EACH of the elements you found, listen for click events and fire the following function when you hear one`.

So - to recap, find all matching elements and fire a function on click event. So far so good, but what happens inside the click event, and how specifically does it know which of the matching elements is the context within the function. Or in your case, how do we stop it affecting both sliders when we only want to affect the one related to the button?

This is the nub of your issue. Look at this line from within your event function:

```
$('.slider-wrapper .slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width() });
```

This line uses a selector `$('.slider-wrapper .slider')` which says 'find ALL elements with this style hierarchy'.  I guess the penny may be dropping with you now. When you have a single slider there is only one matching element, but with two sliders on the page there are two elements that match this selector. The result is what you are experiencing - click one button and both sliders are affected.

The solution is to modify this selector to affect only the element that is in the same slider as the button and to do that we need to refer to the context of the button that got the click. Looking at the HTML, starting from the button, we need to go up to the element with `class='slider-wrapper'` then find the child with `class='slider'`. The selector will need to be:

```
$(this).parents('.slider-wrapper').find('.slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width() });
```

There are a few pieces of jquery magic here to explain. `$(this)` is used inside event functions and refers to the element for which the event is fired. You wired up the selector on the element with `class='prev'`, so when we use $(this) that is the starting element from which we are selecting.

`.parents()` is a selector that traverses up the ancestor tree of elements from the given starting element. Because of jquery chaining (the dots between selectors) we can chain selectors one after the other, so we can walk the DOM by chaining selectors in this way.  Adding `.parents('.slider-wrapper')` says to look for parents that have `class='slider-wrapper'`.

Carrying on the process, `.find('.slider')` uses the find selector to find in the DOM tree from the given element any children with `class='slider'`.

The result of all this is that when you click on the button in slider 1 then the selectors described affect only slider 1. Same for slider 2.

Note that the pattern here of having a broad outer selection to apply event listeners to multiple elements, then using $(this) within the function is exactly the intention of the jquery inventors. Sprinkle in the use of ancestor and child selectors and you have a powerful means to easily achieve navigation and targeting within complex DOM structures.

Background reading: jquery [$(this)](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified), [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Note I fixed an issue in your sample code related to missing variable totalSliders. I used the same technique described above to count the number of sliders in the slider to which the clicked button belongs.

```
var totalSlides = $(this).parents('.slider-wrapper').find('.slide-items').length;
```

I modified your HTML slightly because we do not need 5 sliders to illustrate tge solution.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {


 var sliderWrapper      = $('.slider-wrapper'),
     sliderWrapperWidth = sliderWrapper.width(),
     slider             = $('.slider'),
     slideItems         = $('.slider .slide-items'),
     position           = 0;

 $('.slider-wrapper .slider').each(function() {
  var items = $(this).find('.slide-items').length;
  var sliderBox = $(this);

  slideItems.outerWidth( sliderWrapperWidth / 2 );

  sliderBox.width( slideItems.outerWidth() * items  )
    });


    $('.slider-wrapper .buttons .prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if( position > 0 ) {
            position--;
            $(this).parents('.slider-wrapper').find('.slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width() });
        }
    });

    $('.slider-wrapper .buttons .next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('next');
        // fix - get the number of sections in THIS slider.
        var totalSlides = $(this).parents('.slider-wrapper').find('.slide-items').length;
        if( position < totalSlides - 1 ) {
         position++;
         $(this).parents('.slider-wrapper').find('.slider').css({'right' : position*slideItems.width()         });
     }
    })

})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e5d0d0; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .slider > div p {
  color: purple; 
}

.container .slider-wrapper .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px 0; 
}


.container .slider-wrapper .buttons div {
  background-color: cyan; 
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>1-1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>1-2  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>1-3  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>2-1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>2-2  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="slide-items">
                <p>2-3  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempus diam nec mauris vehicula, eget euismod lorem ultrices. Fusce suscipit nisi nisi, nec fermentum ligula finibus non. Cras scelerisque risus libero, quis faucibus enim elementum non. Ut vitae purus in enim aliquam sollicitudin non et dui. Duis nec varius lectus.</p>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev">
                prev
            </div>

            <div class="next">
                next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```